# How to specify a date range for active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a background job that runs at midnight UTC every night. I need to grab all new records for an active record model whose updated_at is >= the previous midnight (UTC) and the current day's midnight UTC.

What is the best way to do this?

so i need something like:

```
MyRecord.where(updated_at: prior_utc_midnight..tonight_utc_midnight)
```

But i'm unsure how to wrangle the `Time`/`Date` and `DateTime` classes to do what i want.

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to do type conversion unfortunately. That's really the only thing that can help. :(

Comment: Recommend something like where("updated_at >= #{formatted_prior_utc_midnight} and updated_at < #{formatted_tonight_utc_midnight}")

Comment: @abstractx1 my question is more HOW do i wrangle Date and Time classes to get midnight the previous day utc, and to get midnight today utc

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**`beginning_of_day`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) and [**`end_of_day`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-i-end_of_day) methods available.

These helpers will give you the midnight time

```
MyRecord.where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)

#=> SELECT "my_records".* FROM "my_records" WHERE ("my_records"."created_at" BETWEEN '2017-02-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2017-02-24 23:59:59.999999')
```

Also, take a look at these methods

- [**`beginning_of_week`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-c-beginning_of_week)
- [**`yesterday`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-c-yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little wonky, but I think this works:

```
MyRecord.where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", Date.today.to_datetime.new_offset(0) - 1.day, Date.today.to_datetime.new_offset(0))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MyRecord.where("updated_at >= '#{Date.today}' and updated_at < '#{Date.today.next_day}'")
```

The only thing to consider is the timezone of the data in the table. If that is UTC also, then this query should give you the results you have asked for.